# aspx.cs and aspx page problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a sort of a Web-site that lets you search, display(as thumbnails), 
delete images. I've followed the example of this site 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/EasyThumbs.aspx , but i've found 
some problems into the "Default.aspx.cs".
"ThumbFromId doesn't exist in the current context". Now i've noticed the Default.aspx.cs can't see the "objects" of the aspx pages., but i don't know why and how to solve that.

Comment: Have you got any code you can show us? For controls to be seen from the .cs file they need the `runat="server"` attribute

Comment: Here's the entire code http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=17041 . i've checked the runat and it's setted like you said

Answer (score 0):

Is the Codebehind file registered in EasyThumbs.aspx?

CodeBehind="EasyThumbs.ascx.cs"

Comment: Now i've create the web user control EasyThumbs, but i don't understand what did 
you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This issue of "something doesn't exist in the current context" is due to the fact that multiple aspx files are referencing the same cs file. Hence the cs doesn't know which aspx file are you talking about when you are accessing a control.

What you can do is that, search for the string "Default.aspx.cs" in the whole solution. You might end up finding two aspx pages referencing this same cs file.

Hope it helps.